# Rails: Create two navigaton properties when referencing one table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, rails-activerecord

I am creating a table called Routes, which only has destination_airport_id and arrival_airport_id. I want to be able to refer to @route.destination_airport, but Rails does not create these properties. Here's what I tried:

```
  create_table "routes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "departure_airport_id"
    t.integer "arrival_airport_id"
  end
  create_table "airports", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "iata_code"
    t.string "icao_code"
    t.string "international_name"
    t.string "localized_name"
  end
class Airport < ApplicationRecord
    scope :sorted, lambda { order("iata_code ASC") }
    has_many :routes, :foreign_key => :id
end
class Route < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :airport, :foreign_key => "arrival_airport_id"
    belongs_to :airport, :foreign_key => "departure_airport_id"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Route < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :arrival_airport, class_name: 'Airport'
  belongs_to :departure_airport, class_name: 'Airport'
end
```